# df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b'] not working in aws lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services

I was trying to run the code below on aws lambda.

```
s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from csv import reader
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    

    response = s3Client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    
    # Process it
    data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    df= pd.DataFrame(list(reader(data)))
    df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

But it throws out the following error.

```
  "errorMessage": "'a'",
  "errorType": "KeyError"
```

I already added the pandas and aws data wrangler layer, but it is still not working. I was reading the data including column a and b. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Did you try logging `data`, `reader(data)` and `df` from lambda to see what is the content?

Comment: Yeah this sounds like the data isn't what you expect it to be. Follow what @bzu said and come back with what you find

Comment: Read more about `KeyError` [here](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/).